# IOS Backend for User Data

Tags: ios, swift, backend, user-data

I am brand new to ios development and am looking for some advice on the best way to structure my user data and access it throughout my app.

Data is retrieved via HTTPS requests that query a database for the desired information. There are separate calls for the different tables containing information of interest. The returned data is formatted as nested dictionaries where the outermost key is the column and the subsequent dictionary is key-value pairs of the index and the table value. Example:

```
{"column1":{"0":"value1-1", "1":"value1-2", "2":"value1-3"},"column2":{"0":"value2-1", "1":"value2-2", "2":"value2-3"}...}
```

My primary requirement is that I will need to be able to filter this data by the innermost values (some will be dates, some will be numbers, etc). I would like to have the data in a format that will make this simple to do and will not cause delays as there is no limit on the number of possible rows.

I have looked into reconstructing a user-specific SQLite database with the information and querying that throughout the app as necessary. I have also explored dataframes as this app was originally developed in python - don't ask - and relied on pandas dataframes.

I know this decision will impact me heavily and am trying to do my best to make an informed decision. I appreciate any feedback and am happy to give more useful context that might be missing.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLite database for persistent storage. This is ideal for your main requirement of filtering the data. You should also create a structure or a class modelled on your data to store and use during runtime. You can refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes) for deciding between a class or structure.

Comment: If you have any follow-up questions id be happy to answer them.